# How to do addition where column data type is `varchar`?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am working on a logic where based on certain number of occurrence of `DesiredDate` field, `DesiredTime` should be incremented. The problem is `DesiredTime` is `varchar` so I cannot do addition in that field. What would the best approach to achieve this goal?

For example, if `10/08/2015` occurred 3 times then `DesiredTime` is `11:45AM`. On 4th `10/08/2015` entry, `DesiredTime` should be `11:17AM`, 5th should be `11:19` & so on.

Approach - 1:

```
UPDATE OrderInfo SET DesiredTime = DesiredTime + 2 WHERE OrderID = 39418875
```

Error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '11:15AM' to data
>   type int.

Approach - 2:

```
select * from OrderInfo 
where CONVERT(int, DesiredTime) ='11:45AM' 
  and OrderDate = '10/7/2015' 
  and RestaurantID = 4007
```

Error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '11:15AM' to data
>   type int.

Current Behaviour:

```
DesiredDate DesiredTime
----------- -----------
10/08/2015  11:15AM
10/08/2015  11:15AM
10/08/2015  11:15AM
10/08/2015  11:15AM
10/08/2015  11:15AM
```

Expected Behaviour:

```
DesiredDate DesiredTime
----------- -----------
10/08/2015  11:15AM
10/08/2015  11:15AM
10/08/2015  11:15AM
10/08/2015  11:17AM
10/08/2015  11:19AM
```

Comment: I wish I had a nickel for every question on this site about operations on Date / Time values not stored as Date / Time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your logic at all, but to add time to the time value stored as varchar you can use `cast` to convert it to a proper `time` type value and then use `dateadd` to add time to it.

```
dateadd(minute,2,cast(desiredtime as time))
```

This should hopefully get you started.

Comment: Just an aside, because the date is stored in a separate column this doesn't handle if you increment the time past the end of the day.  You'll end up with the right time on the wrong day.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff Indeed. It might be better to construct a new date from the date and time parts and increment that. I didn't really understand the objective so I can't say.